# PHP Google Static Maps V2 error

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I want to display a static map image with 3 markers, and somehow it is not working. It works with one marker, but doesn't display an image when I add more markers. The output url displays an image if I direct the browser to it, but doesn't seem to work in the php page.

```
<?php
    $lat1=61.212311;
    $lng1=61.211123;
    $lat2=61.421113;
    $lng2=61.411123;
    $lat3=61.931121;
    $lng3=61.912113;
    $url="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=400x400&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:S%7C".$lat1.",".$lng1."&markers=size:tiny%7Ccolor:green%7C".$lat2.",".$lng2."&markers=size:mid%7Ccolor:red%7Clabel:C%7C".$lat3.",".$lng3."&sensor=false&key=";
    $src = htmlspecialchars($url);
    echo $src;
?>
<html>
<body>
    <img src="<? echo $src; ?>" />
</body>
</html>
```

I am putting my API key, that is not the error.

Comment: try to remove echo $src; i think i will work

Answer (score 0):

you are defining variable `$url1` and using `$url`, so change:

```
$src = htmlspecialchars($url);
```

to

```
$src = htmlspecialchars($url1);
```

and remove `echo $src;` from top

Comment: Okay I may have posted an old code here. It is written correctly in the php page, Sorry for the error. Anything else you could find ?

Comment: somehow now it works. I was playing with this code, and now it works! Dont know what changed, maybe a silly mistake here and there. thanks sudhir for your time !